# Deserialize <![CDATA[x]> Into Class Object C#

Tags: .net, deserialization, cdata

I have data that looks like this:

```
                <City Code="LON">
                    <![CDATA[London]]>
                </City>
                <Item Code="IBI3">
                    <![CDATA[IBIS EXCEL]]>
                </Item>
```

And I have classes that look like this that were auto-generated:

```
public class City
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item" )]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

When I deserialize the xml string, I get a null value for Text....how do I deserialize this CDATA?

Comment: I've tried using XmlCDataSection and XmlCharacterData as the types for the Text property....to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I was using the RestSharp serializer, switched to Xml.Serializer and all is well